# How to hide Ejabberd data from port scannig

Tags: ejabberd

I have ejabberd 16 running on ubuntu 16.04. I have secured the ejabberd with TLS encryption. But on port scanning I am able to see the stream_id, protocol, protocol version etc. Is there any way to hide that ? I tried disabling `mod_version` but there is no use. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to hide: `stream id` is a random number and `version` is always `1.0`. The only problem might be a host name, but in recent versions ejabberd doesn't advertise it when generating an error for malformed XML.

Comment: But in our old servers all these are hidden, when the previous developer compiled the source code he managed to hide it somehow

Comment: So ask him to apply his patches